# Private Downloads page

Tags: forms, content

I'm attempting to make the following scenario in EE *without* utilizing membership. A form is on page 1. Upon successful submission of form, user is taken to page 2 which contains content only accessible after form is filled out. More than likely using FreeForm for my form submissions. The purpose of this is to just gather information about the people wanting the form-blocked content.

I'm just trying to wrap my head around how to do this without someone being able to hack the url to page 2...ie..

page 1 form would be at:

domain.com/form

upon successful submit, would be directed to page 2:

domain.com/form/content

Can anyone think of a different or better way of handling this so that the url cannot be hacked? Membership seems like the obvious choice, but some of these users will potentially already be members of a different group, some may not. Thanks for any help!

Comment: You can allow page access with members by using conditionals to test if the person is in member group 1 or 2. I'd definitely go the Members route. The only other way to block a page is to use .htpassword but then users would still need a way to "login" to view the page.

Comment: Thanks Mark! I've probably been overthinking this thing...seems like membership in a different group is the way to go.

Comment: Indeed! We're all guilty of that :) I"ll make my comment the answer if you wouldn't mind accepting it to boost my ego...er, my rep :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can allow page access with members by using conditionals to test if the person is in member group 1 or 2. I'd definitely go the Members route. The only other way to block a page is to use .htpassword but then users would still need a way to "login" to view the page.